# how to profile concreate function or segment of code in php?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

Say I have an application on production server and I need to profile some segment of code, but not the whole application, cause it slows drastically.

So I need something like this:

`enable_profiler();

function_with_bottle_neck();

disable_profiler();`

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xhprof. And you can write something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your_ip') {
 enable_profiler();
}
function_with_bottle_neck();

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your_ip') {
 disable_profiler();
}
```